# Rounding to Arbitrary Levels of Precision in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math

In JavaScript, how can I convert 3.14159 to 3.14. If the value is 3.14659 I expect it to be 3.15.

Answer (score 1):

```
value = 3.14159;    
Math.round(value * 100) / 100;
```

Comment: 3.14159 is always going to be 3.14

Comment: Yep, you're right. @kazi Tanvir Ahsan expects a wrong value. `value.toFixed(2)` would be sufficient btw.

Comment: Yes value.toFixed(2) should also work.

Comment: Yes.I think toFixed is more appropriate.var num = 3.14659;var n=num.toFixed(2); alert(n); gives me 3.15